# Number of ways to choose $k$ non-overlapping rectangles in an $n\times m$ grid

Tags: combinatorics

I'd like to find the number of ways to choose $k$ non-overlapping rectangles in an $n\times m$ grid, for $k=1\text{ to }6$. Their edges must be parallel to the x-/y-axis, and their vertices must be on lattice points. They need not have the same shape. The order of the $k$ rectangles doesn't matter.

I've figure out for any fixed value of $k$, the answer must be a polynomial of degree $4k$ (or degree $2k$ w.r.t. $n$ or $m$).

Clearly the answer for $k=1$ is
$$
\frac{nm(n+1)(m+1)}{4}
$$

With a laptop and interpolation, I've figure out the answer for $k=2$:
$$
\frac{nm(n+1)(m+1)[5nm(n+1)(m+1)-4(n^2+m^2+n+m+1)]}{288}
$$

However, the number grows too fast, as counting the ways for $n=m=6, k=5$ already took my laptop $40$ seconds (and the result is $1713629104$). Is there a better way to solve it?